# Do GCP Internal Load Balancers support gRPC with Serverless Negs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I am running a number of Cloud Run services which all have VPC access via a VPC connector and setting all egress to run through this connector. I have an ILB set up which points to a Regional Backend Service with Serverless Network Endpoint Group type. When you select this type you are unable to choose the protocol for the service (HTTP, HTTPS, HTTP/2)

The receiving Cloud Run is set to ingress unauthenticated and to allow internal/cloud-load-balancing.

When my client tries to send messages to my server via an address that resolves to the ILB it fails with a very non-descript error: `rpc error: code = Unknown desc =`.

I have tried using the direct cloud run url as opposed to going via my ILB and this does work. I would prefer to use my internal DNS though if possible.

Comment: Did you read this section? But, because it's in preview, I assume it's not fully supported yet. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal#grpc_support

Comment: Yeah, it didn't seem like that section addresses using in conjunction with Serverless NEGs and I think you are correct that it's just not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The `rpc error: code = Unknown desc =` is indicative of the ILB encountering difficulty in routing the traffic. Ensure that your routing rules include an additional host entry specifying your `domain:port`.